# How can I scale my web in code?

Tags: web-applications, scale

I have a webapp running my web and api in Azure on a WebApp. Is it possible to scale my webapp to more instances using code in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the deployment model you web app is based on (Classic of ARM) you can either use the Azure Management Libraries and change the 'serverfarm' property of your Web Site. Alternatively you could script updating the ARM template with updated properties its the hosting plan.